# which is better for continuous stream of data- HBase vs cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hbase, bigdata

which is better cassandra or hbase for continous stream of data? Which is faster and more fault tolerent?

Comment: Sorry, you will probably not get a clear answer here. It's subjective, depends on your data, your HW, your usage, your queries, your performance targets, your throughput vs. latency targets, etc etc. I'm afraid you'll need to learn both and run a POC or hire professional help.

Comment: in addition to @PetrJaneček (do a POC for your specific use case) - another question is if you want to stream data to or from cassandra. You can have a look at Apache Spark Streaming, Apache Kafka - see for example https://academy.datastax.com/resources/apache-spark-streaming